# Tesseract error. Illegal min or max specification

Tags: java, linux, tesseract

Trying to run sample code from here http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html I got an error saying

```
Error: Illegal min or max specification!
signal_termination_handler:Error:Signal_termination_handler called:Code 5002
```

I found solution e.g. here https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=228 ppl say that setting locale is enough to get rid of error. My problem is that I write it in Java not C++ and I cannot find anywhere how I can set locale in my code as they did it like that

```
 #include <locale.h>
 setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

I was trying to use `setTessVariable(String, String)` method but it didn't work. I will mention that my pdf files, which are on input, are in polish language so if someone know how I should set these locale I would be grateful. I try to run it on linux x64 platform.

Comment: Can you `export LC_NUMERIC="C"` at the command line when you launch your program?

Comment: Well I didn't check your solution before I started bounty. Now I checked it and it works. It was a problem with decimal sign which is a colon in my country.

Comment: Someone needs to answer the question or the bounty will be lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 'Can you export LC_NUMERIC="C" at the command line when you launch
>   your program?'

–  nguyenq

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal, **export LC_NUMERIC="C"** and launch Eclipse or NetBeans from there also (**important!**).

Comment: Why are you responding to my resolved question from year and a half ago and what is more you just copied the answer which already was marked as correct?