# Java + Tomcat + tesseract+ OCR issue on locale property not set

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, opencv, tesseract

I have a project architecture using opencv and tesseract. The project if fully configured using references to native libraries with java.

I have a problem that comes when my locale config on linux LC_NUMERIC is set to en_US or any other rather than "C" , so my application doesn't run properly (see https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#actual_tessdata_num_entries_%3C=_TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Ass)

It is curious because running on eclipse, when the LC_NUMERIC is set to "C" everything goes fine, so I started to figure out that tomcat's catalina.sh or startup.sh have some configuration or ambient configuration that doesn't keep my app running properly.

Do any of you guys have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579290/tesseract-error-illegal-min-or-max-specification

Comment: I tried and still happens. The trace is not " Error: Illegal min or max specification!" , it is: "actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file tessdatamanager.cpp, line 53"

Comment: Do you use the correct version of .traineddata file for your tesseract version?

Comment: Thanks much for your response. You are right, the version was missing, it must be some problem on the packaging. Thanks much, bye